# For what is value used in select in html form

Tags: html, forms

Can anyone help me and tell for what is value used in select tag, in html forms. like below:

```
<select name="country">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <option value="1">USA</option>
    <option value="2">Canada</option>
        </select>
```

I know that when value is used in button, it shows the text that appears on the button like below:

```
 <input class="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Sign in" >
```

But i dont understand for what it is used in select tag, because the value that appears is USA not 1.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When a user selects USA, 1 will be sent and when he selects Canada 2 will be sent (from your example). If you need to send as USA or Canada, make your option with value as USA and Canada instead of 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the select tag will be sent back to server.

See the database table below:

```
id,         country
1,          USA
2,          CANADA
```

Using the id field you will query database but this id won't make sense to user. So rather then seeing ids they will see country names. Hence the text between the option tags. And when they submit the form the id will get post back to server so you can query database.

Answer (score 1):

An option value in a select tag is what is sent when a form is submitted. The value sent is the one that the user has selected in the dropdown. In this case, if I selected USA, it would send a value of "1"

Answer (score 0):

The value is what is sent to the server when the form is submitted with that option selected.